# IDE that can work on an existing website?

Tags: language-agnostic

Here is my problem: i am taking over development of a website that already exists and is published. I was hoping to use something simple like iWeb to work on the site, but iWeb seems to have no way to work on a project that wasn't started within iWeb. Is there some standard IDE/editor/dev package that is designed to handle this?

Comment: What language is it written in?

Comment: It's currently a vanilla HTML product based site.

Comment: So is it solely html?  I.e., There's nothing dynamic?  Do you plan on adding dynamic content to the site?  If so, what language will that be?

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is pretty good at looking at what is there already, and making it easy to make further changes. The design and code views should allow a non technical person to make non-radical changes for most sites.

Beyond that it will depend entirely on how the site is built, if it's a few static HTML pages dreamweaver or its ilk will do fine. If it's a heavy drupal or wordpress site with multiple plugins and customizations you're going to need to use the built in UI to make changes, or contact a developer familiar with the technology used.